# Show PSD Preview in PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, psd

Is there a way to show the preview of a PSD file in a `PictureBox` or `ListView`?

Can it be done without the help of a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit native solution for this, but there are various libraries and projects that you can use.

Your best option may be to start with these CodeProject articles:

[Yet Another PSD Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/PSDParser.aspx)

[Reading Adobe Photoshop Images](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/simplepsd.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried competent_tech's links and they don't work with most of psd files.
This one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10398/Import-Adobe-Photoshop-psd-images is a little better, but still doesn't work with newer psd files.

This one: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php works fine (I checked the compiled convert.exe from the installation folder), and there is a .NET wrapper:
http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/, which I failed to use. Anyway you could run an external process of convert.exe to save the file as a common format and load it to the PictureBox.

If you have time to read code, the library is open source.